# Files and folder count within a doc library (consolidated count of files and folder on each level)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

is there a way to create a view for a user in a library where at the folder level user can see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dtQq.jpg) , like a consolidated view of how many folders and files are there in a folder? , is this possible to something like this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the OOB column **Folder Child Count** and **Item Child Count** to show how many files and folders are there in a folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to create a custom view with consolidated view as mentioned in https://imgur.com/a/4LBiiZr , any suggestions?  @Julie_MSFT

Comment: No, there is no such custom view in library.